# How do i define the range on one of my axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

My first time posting here so firstly sorry for my lack of communication skills.

I'm trying to learn matplotlib for a 3d visualization in my jupyter notebook,

So far I have made a messy cube of a 3d plot, such as the following:

[3d cube data visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luqdu.png)

but as you can see, the Y axis is not presented very nice. I would like to prolong it if possible. That in a way it could be more a rectangle than the cube that it is. Does anyone know how to define the range of the Y axis?

Working code example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')

endingMerchantSales = [100,639,3068,14727,70692,339325,1628777]
salesPL = [24500,133164.4,384675.168,1546967.643,6225678.340,29571844.556,129179928.610]
salesMultiplier = [ 16.33 , 21.47 , 23.97 , 26.52 , 26.52 , 27.79 , 27.79 ]


ax.scatter (salesPL, endingMerchantSales , salesMultiplier, c='r',marker='o')
ax.plot (salesPL, endingMerchantSales , salesMultiplier, c='r')
ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')
plt.show()
```

Could this be fixed by specifying the range of my XYZ axis? or is there some way else I could present this? If anyone could help, would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are missing a value for `salesMultiplier`

Comment: Thank you! I have revised my problem a bit,

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html